# Writing scons script to handle compilation of files in many subdirectories

Tags: c++, build, makefile, scons, subdirectory

I've got a project which consists of many files in subdirectories. I have a simple Makefile which handles the compilation. It looks like this:

```
CC = g++ -Wall -ansi -pedantic 
all:
$(CC) -O2 engine/core/*.cpp engine/objects3d/*.cpp engine/display/*.cpp engine/io  /*.cpp engine/math/*.cpp engine/messages/*.cpp  *.cpp -o project1 -lGL -lGLU -lX11 `sdl-config --cflags --libs`

clean:
@echo Cleaning up...
@rm project1
@echo Done.
```

However I need to migrate to SCons. I have no idea how to write a script that would automatically handle finding all the *.cpp files in subdirectories and included them in the compilation process.

Comment: You can find some decent tutorials here: http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/index.html

Comment: That defeats the whole purpose of using a tool to manage the build; every time you'll get a full compilation of the entire source tree. Do you really want to rebuild everything from scratch if you change a single character in a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to do what you have in your Makefile in SCons. You should put this Python code in a file at the root of the project called `SConstruct`, and just simply execute `scons`. To clean, execute `scons -c`

```
env = Environment()
env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-Wall', '-ansi', '-pedantic', '-O2', '-lGL', '-lGLU', '-lX11'])

# Determine compiler and linker flags for SDL
env.ParseConfig('sdl-config --cflags')
env.ParseConfig('sdl-config --libs')

# Remember that the SCons Glob() function is not recursive
env.Program(target='project1',
            source=[Glob('engine/core/*.cpp'),
                    Glob('engine/objects3d/*.cpp'),
                    Glob('engine/display/*.cpp)',
                    Glob('engine/io/*.cpp'),
                    Glob('engine/math/*.cpp'),
                    Glob('engine/messages/*.cpp'),
                    Glob('*.cpp')])
```

[Here](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL%3aTutorials%3aSetup#SCons) is a link for using SDL with SCons.

And here is info on the [SCons ParseConfig() function](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x1898.html).

Comment: Thanks, it worked but still I've got problems with SDL. It gives me the following response: 
      `g++ -o EnemyShip.o -c -Wall -ansi -pedantic -O2 -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lSDL -I/usr/include/sdl EnemyShip.cpp
In file included from engine/core/engine.h:4:0,
                 from EnemyShip.h:4,
                 from EnemyShip.cpp:1:
engine/core/core.h:8:18: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory`

So 'sdl-config --cflags --libs' is needed. I checked it and the following command works: 
`g++ -o EnemyShip.o -c -Wall -ansi -pedantic -O2 -lGL -lGLU -lX11 `sdl-config --cflags --libs` EnemyShip.cpp`

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer and added a link to an SDL page and how to use it with SCons.

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked. I still have some problems with linker but I want to try to solve it myself. Solved :).

Comment: @PawełJastrzębski, ok glad to hear it worked. Remember if you have linker problems, you can set the libs to compile with like this: env.Append(LIBS=[]) and the lib paths like this: env.Append(LIBPATH=[])  No need to include the '-l' nor the '-L' flags, SCons will do that for you. Good Luck!!

Comment: Yes, everything is compiling smoothly. Thanks very much again :).